# Segmentation Fault during rails assets:precompile on Apple Silicon (M3) with Ruby 3.3.0 in Docker (with Kamal)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrent-ruby, propshaft

I'm encountering a segmentation fault issue when trying to build a Docker image for a new Rails application on my MacBook Pro with Apple Silicon (M3). The fault occurs specifically at the `RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile` step during the Docker build.

Some key points:

This issue happens on my MacBook with Apple Silicon (M3); I don't have access to an Intel Apple machine anymore.

Building the image only for `amd64` works fine, suggesting the issue might be related to the ARM architecture.

Removing bootsnap from the Gemfile and in the codebase didn't resolve the issue.

I saw some segfault issues that were suggesting an older version of Docker (4.18) would fix the issue, but it didn't.

Likewise, switching to gRPC FUSE with Virtualization Framework off didn't fix the issue.

However, **switching to Ruby 3.2.2 resolved the issue**.

The Rails app is very simple, created with `rails new ohanami -a propshaft -c tailwind`. You can see the failing app here: https://github.com/miharekar/ohanami/tree/d2170a657a8e6e3d591436b9371e7b1f444220d5

I'm guessing the problem is either with Ruby 3.3.0 or in concurrent-ruby, or in propshaft. Don't know how to investigate further, or where to report it.

What would you suggest I do?

Here's the backtrace:

```
#16 [build 5/5] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:14: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0024ffff93e406c0
#16 0.342 ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [aarch64-linux]
#16 0.342
#16 0.342 -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
#16 0.342 c:0079 p:---- s:0371 e:000370 CFUNC  :resume
#16 0.342 c:0078 p:0007 s:0367 E:0003c0 BLOCK  /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:14 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0077 p:---- s:0364 e:000363 CFUNC  :synchronize
#16 0.342 c:0076 p:0026 s:0360 E:000ee8 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:12
#16 0.342 c:0075 p:0007 s:0355 e:000354 CLASS  /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:18
#16 0.342 c:0074 p:0025 s:0352 e:000351 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:5 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0073 p:---- s:0349 e:000348 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0072 p:0030 s:0344 e:000343 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0071 p:0041 s:0338 e:000337 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/reentrant_read_write_lock.rb:7 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0070 p:---- s:0335 e:000334 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0069 p:0030 s:0330 e:000329 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0068 p:0047 s:0324 e:000323 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomics.rb:8 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0067 p:---- s:0321 e:000320 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0066 p:0030 s:0316 e:000315 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0065 p:0029 s:0310 e:000309 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent.rb:6 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0064 p:---- s:0307 e:000306 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0063 p:0030 s:0302 e:000301 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0062 p:0005 s:0296 e:000295 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/string_deduper.rb:4 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0061 p:---- s:0293 e:000292 CFUNC  :require_relative
#16 0.342 c:0060 p:0025 s:0288 e:000287 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo.rb:25 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0059 p:---- s:0285 e:000284 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0058 p:0030 s:0280 e:000279 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0057 p:0005 s:0274 e:000273 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:3 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0056 p:---- s:0271 e:000270 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0055 p:0030 s:0266 e:000265 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0054 p:0017 s:0260 e:000259 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb:5 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0053 p:---- s:0257 e:000256 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0052 p:0030 s:0252 e:000251 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0051 p:0065 s:0246 e:000245 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:14 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0050 p:---- s:0243 e:000242 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0049 p:0030 s:0238 e:000237 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0048 p:0005 s:0232 e:000231 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:3 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0047 p:---- s:0229 e:000228 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0046 p:0030 s:0224 e:000223 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0045 p:0011 s:0218 e:000217 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/json.rb:4 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0044 p:---- s:0215 e:000214 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0043 p:0030 s:0210 e:000209 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0042 p:0011 s:0204 e:000203 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/messages/metadata.rb:4 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0041 p:---- s:0201 e:000200 CFUNC  :require_relative
#16 0.342 c:0040 p:0011 s:0196 e:000195 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/messages/codec.rb:4 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0039 p:---- s:0193 e:000192 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0038 p:0030 s:0188 e:000187 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0037 p:0023 s:0182 e:000181 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:6 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0036 p:---- s:0179 e:000178 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0035 p:0030 s:0174 e:000173 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0034 p:0017 s:0168 e:000167 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:5 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0033 p:---- s:0165 e:000164 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0032 p:0030 s:0160 e:000159 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0031 p:0011 s:0154 e:000153 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:4 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0030 p:---- s:0151 e:000150 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0029 p:0030 s:0146 e:000145 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0028 p:0041 s:0140 e:000139 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:9 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0027 p:---- s:0137 e:000136 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0026 p:0030 s:0132 e:000131 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0025 p:0059 s:0126 e:000125 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails.rb:15 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0024 p:---- s:0123 e:000122 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0023 p:0030 s:0118 e:000117 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0022 p:0011 s:0112 e:000111 TOP    /rails/config/application.rb:5 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0021 p:---- s:0109 e:000108 CFUNC  :require_relative
#16 0.342 c:0020 p:0005 s:0104 e:000103 TOP    /rails/Rakefile:6 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0019 p:---- s:0101 e:000100 CFUNC  :load
#16 0.342 c:0018 p:0005 s:0096 e:000095 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29
#16 0.342 c:0017 p:0143 s:0091 e:000090 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:734
#16 0.342 c:0016 p:0003 s:0085 e:000084 BLOCK  /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:126
#16 0.342 c:0015 p:0002 s:0082 e:000081 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:208
#16 0.342 c:0014 p:0004 s:0077 e:000076 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125
#16 0.342 c:0013 p:0021 s:0073 e:000072 BLOCK  /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:43
#16 0.342 c:0012 p:0023 s:0069 e:000068 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59
#16 0.342 c:0011 p:0021 s:0063 e:000062 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:41
#16 0.342 c:0010 p:0010 s:0056 e:000055 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20
#16 0.342 c:0009 p:0032 s:0049 e:000048 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:156
#16 0.342 c:0008 p:0035 s:0042 e:000041 BLOCK  /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:73
#16 0.342 c:0007 p:0015 s:0039 e:000038 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:149
#16 0.342 c:0006 p:0048 s:0033 e:000032 METHOD /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:69
#16 0.342 c:0005 p:0038 s:0022 e:000021 TOP    /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0004 p:---- s:0017 e:000016 CFUNC  :require
#16 0.342 c:0003 p:0030 s:0012 e:000011 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74
#16 0.342 c:0002 p:0024 s:0006 e:000005 EVAL   ./bin/rails:4 [FINISH]
#16 0.342 c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:000cf0 DUMMY  [FINISH]
#16 0.342
#16 0.342 -- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
#16 0.342 ./bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:69:in `invoke'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:149:in `with_argv'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:73:in `block in invoke'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:156:in `invoke_rake'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:41:in `with_rake'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:43:in `block in with_rake'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `load_rakefile'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:208:in `standard_exception_handling'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:126:in `block in load_rakefile'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:734:in `raw_load_rakefile'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
#16 0.342 /rails/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /rails/Rakefile:6:in `require_relative'
#16 0.342 /rails/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/messages/codec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/messages/codec.rb:4:in `require_relative'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/messages/metadata.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/json.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo.rb:25:in `require_relative'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/string_deduper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomics.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/reentrant_read_write_lock.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:18:in `<module:Concurrent>'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:12:in `mutex_owned_per_thread?'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:12:in `synchronize'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:14:in `block in mutex_owned_per_thread?'
#16 0.342 /usr/local/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/lock_local_var.rb:14:in `resume'
#16 0.342
#16 0.342 -- Threading information ---------------------------------------------------
#16 0.342 Total ractor count: 1
#16 0.342 Ruby thread count for this ractor: 1
#16 0.342
#16 0.342 -- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
#16 0.342   x0: 0x0000aaab05e23b50  x1: 0x0000aaab06c75e80  x2: 0x0000ffffd6038650
#16 0.342   x3: 0x0000ffff79b3ff60  x4: 0x0000ffff79b40018  x5: 0x0000ffff79b60000
#16 0.342   x6: 0x0000ffff9438db88  x7: 0x0000000000000000 x18: 0x000000000000018f
#16 0.342  x19: 0x0000000000000000 x20: 0x0000000000000000 x21: 0x0000000000000000
#16 0.342  x22: 0x0000000000000000 x23: 0x0000000000000000 x24: 0x0000000000000000
#16 0.342  x25: 0x0000000000000000 x26: 0x0000000000000000 x27: 0x0000000000000000
#16 0.342  x28: 0x0000000000000000 x29: 0x0000000000000000  sp: 0x0000ffff79b40000
#16 0.342  fau: 0x0024ffff93e406c0
#16 0.342
#16 0.342 -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
#16 0.344 Segmentation fault
#16 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139
------
 > [build 5/5] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile:
0.342   x3: 0x0000ffff79b3ff60  x4: 0x0000ffff79b40018  x5: 0x0000ffff79b60000
0.342   x6: 0x0000ffff9438db88  x7: 0x0000000000000000 x18: 0x000000000000018f
0.342  x19: 0x0000000000000000 x20: 0x0000000000000000 x21: 0x0000000000000000
0.342  x22: 0x0000000000000000 x23: 0x0000000000000000 x24: 0x0000000000000000
0.342  x25: 0x0000000000000000 x26: 0x0000000000000000 x27: 0x0000000000000000
0.342  x28: 0x0000000000000000 x29: 0x0000000000000000  sp: 0x0000ffff79b40000
0.342  fau: 0x0024ffff93e406c0
0.342
0.342 -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0.344 Segmentation fault
------
Dockerfile:39
--------------------
  37 |
  38 |     # Precompiling assets for production without requiring secret RAILS_MASTER_KEY
  39 | >>> RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile
  40 |
  41 |     # Final stage for app image
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139
```

Comment: Probably this: https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/issues/1023

Answer (score 17):

As pointed out by @smathy this bug was caught and fixed already: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/9371

Until it's released as part of 3.3.1 you have to build Ruby yourself if you want the patch. Here's how I did it: https://github.com/miharekar/ohanami/commit/14e75194e4cada3432fc7f734894f0dce8304096

Comment: Can confirm it works